# Solving Discrete Markov Chain with diagonal band matrix.

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

I am trying to model a certain process as a Discrete Markov Chain.
My system has $N+1$ states: $X=0, \ldots N$, and I can assume that the $(N+1)\times (N+1)$ transition matrix $T$ has the general form

$$T=\left(
        \begin{matrix}
        1 - p_0 & p_0 & 0 & \cdots & \cdots&\cdots & 0  \\
        0 & 1-p_1 & p_1 & 0 & \cdots & \cdots& 0 \\
       0 & 0 & \ddots & \ddots & 0 & \cdots&0  \\
       0 & 0 &  0 &1-p_n & p_n & 0 & 0 \\
       0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0 & \ddots & \ddots&0  \\
       0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & 0 & 1-p_{N-1}&p_{N-1} \\
       0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & 0 &1  \\
        \end{matrix}
\right)
$$

where the $p_n$ are estimated from experimental data, and in principle (though it is unlikely) for some $j$ it might be $p_j=0$ or $p_j = 1$.

What I am interested for my evaluation in is the expected value of the distribution at the $m-$th step, $m \le N$, assuming that my process start from state $X=0$.

I am new to the study of Markov chains, so I'd like some advices on how to proceed correctly. And possibly some smart trick to solve the chain.

As far as I have understood I have to evaluate $T^m$. The first row of $T^m$ is then the distribution of probability at m-th time step assuming that my process starts from the state $X=0$.

The particular structure of the matrix would help me in solving the calculations? How to treat the cases $p_j=0$ and $p_j=1$?

Thanks a lot for the advices and help!

Answer (score -1):

Diagonalize $T$ with the diagonal matrix $D$ and change of basis matrix $C$. To find the diagonal matrix $D$, find the eigenvalues of $T$, then $D$ is the diagonal matrix with its entries as its eigenvalues. Then matrix $C$ has its columns as the eigenvectors of $T$.

Then you'll have $T = CDC^{-1}$. Then $T^m=(CDC^{-1})(CDC^{-1})\cdots(CDC^{-1})$ (you're multiplying $CDC^{-1}$ by itself m times. Observing the left side we see be associativity $CD(C^{-1}C)D(C^{-1}C)\cdots(C^{-1}C)DC^{-1}$ Therefore we have the Identity matrix in every parenthesis and we have $T^m = CD^mC^{-1}$ which is a standard result for any diagonalizable matrix $T$.

Comment: thanks. If I remind correctly, for the particular matrix under consideration, the eigenvalues correspond to the entries on the main diagonal. If for some $j$, $p_j = 1$ I might have then a 0 eigenvalue, and the T matrix would not be diagonalizable. What should I do then?

Comment: Doesn't matter, you can have 0 as an eigenvalue for a matrix T and it is still diagonalizable

Comment: Do you honestly believe an upper triangular matrix may be diagonalized?

Comment: Yes I do, do you not?

Comment: 1 2, 0 2 (a 2X2 matrix reading row 1, row 2) is upper diagonal with eigenvalues 2 and 1 with eigenvectors <1,0> and <2,1>! now please unreject my comment

Comment: The meaning of *unrejecting a comment* is not clear to me but, as you know, some more care is needed here. Consider, for example, the case p_0=p_1. (My first comment should have read: *Do you honestly believe any upper triangular matrix may be diagonalized?*, sorry for this.)

Comment: I just wanted to ask myself what happens in the case were I have eigenvalues with multiplicity larger than 1. As far as I remember in that case you can reduce it to Jordan form, but not diagonalize it.